# count the number of occurrences of each item in a list

Tags: list, netlogo

I have a list with 20 items and I want to count the number of occurrences of each item in list. I know code below

```
to-report frequency [i lst]
    report length filter [? = i] list
end
```

but I do not want to write 20 lines like

```
let C1 frequency 1 (list1)
let C2 frequency 2 (list1)
.
.
.
let C20 frequency 20 (list1)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's:

```
map [frequency ? list1] n-values 20 [? + 1]
```

Sample run:

```
observer> set list1 [1 4 4 7 10 10 10 14]
observer> show map [frequency ? list1] n-values 20 [? + 1]
observer: [1 0 0 2 0 0 1 0 0 3 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0]
```

For NetLogo 6, OP's function would be this:

```
to-report frequency [an-item a-list]
    report length (filter [ i -> i = an-item] a-list)
end
```

Making a frequency list is revised like this:

```
map [ i -> frequency i list1] (n-values 20 [i -> i])
```